# In the lets-lens tutorial, how do you refactor out the call to traverse in order to implement over?

Tags: haskell, traversal, functor, haskell-lens

In [the exercises](https://github.com/NICTA/lets-lens/blob/master/src/Lets/Lens.hs) I have implemented `fmapT`:

```
-- Let's remind ourselves of Traversable, noting Foldable and Functor.
--
-- class (Foldable t, Functor t) => Traversable t where
--   traverse ::
--     Applicative f => 
--     (a -> f b)
--     -> t a
--     -> f (t b)

-- | Observe that @fmap@ can be recovered from @traverse@ using @Identity@.
--
-- /Reminder:/ fmap :: Functor t => (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
fmapT ::
  Traversable t =>
  (a -> b)
  -> t a
  -> t b
fmapT =
  error "todo: fmapT"
```

Now how do I implement `over`?

```
-- | Let's refactor out the call to @traverse@ as an argument to @fmapT@.

over ::
  ((a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t)
  -> (a -> b)
  -> s
  -> t
over = error "undefined"
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation on `over` function?

Comment: add some edit on question, and actually i don't  know what's `over` for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `fmapT` using `traverse` as:

```
fmapT f s = runIdentity (traverse (Identity . f) s)
```

now the next exercise is to refactor this function by providing `traverse` as a parameter rather than hard-coding it in the definition. If you choose `Identity` as the applicative type constructor then the type of `traverse` is:

```
(Traversable t) => (a -> Identity b) -> t a -> Identity (t b)
```

if you provide this as a parameter to `fmapT` you end up with something like `over`:

```
over' :: Traversable t => ((a -> Identity b) -> t a -> Identity (t b)) -> (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
over' l f s = runIdentity (l (Identity . f) s)
```

since the `Traversable` constraint exists in `traverse` it is not required by `over'` which has the more general type of `over` given in the exercise i.e.

```
over :: ((a -> Identity b) -> (s -> Identity t)) -> (a -> b) -> s -> t
```

and

```
over' =  over traverse
```

Comment: I'd say `over l f = runIdentity . l (Identity . f)` is clearer, or even (using `Data.Profunctor.Unsafe`) `over l f = runIdentity #. l (Identity #. f)`. This clarifies that, operationally, `over` is just the identity function.

Comment: yes, `over l f s = runIdentity (l (Identity . f) s)` is ok, but as it say: `-- | Let's refactor out the call to @traverse@ as an argument to @fmapT@.`.your implementation is not satistfy it.